# Pandas `yerr` after `groupby` generates "ConversionError"

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, group-by

I am trying to use `pandas.plot(type=bar)` to plot a bar with errors.
I have some variables for each sample, each sample belonging to a group.
Toy example:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({
    'U':   [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ], 
    'V':   [ 5, 6, 7, 8 ], 
    'grp': [ 1, 1, 2, 2 ]     })
```

I have created mean and std for each group as follows:

```
uv_agg = df.groupby('grp').agg([mean, std])
```

The resulting table has format

```
       U           V 
       mean  std   mean  std
grp
1
2
```

I can plot bars using

```
uv_agg.plot( kind='bar', y=('U','mean') )  # works!
```

but when I try error bars with

```
uv_agg.plot( kind='bar', y=('U','mean'), yerr=('U','std') )
```

I get

```
ConversionError: Failed to convert value(s) to axis units: array(['U', 'std'], dtype='<U6')
```

I have tried stepping through the plot code but can't get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter `y` takes "label, position or list of label, positions" which is why `y=('U','mean')` works. However, the parameter `yerr` takes "DataFrame, Series, array-like, dict and str" so (for example) you can use `uv_agg['U']['std']` :

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'U': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                   'V': [5, 6, 7, 8],
                   'grp': [1, 1, 2, 2]
                   })

uv_agg = df.groupby('grp').agg([np.mean, np.std])
uv_agg.plot(kind='bar', y=('U', 'mean'), yerr=uv_agg['U']['std'], capsize=4, rot=0)
plt.show()
```

[image: error bars]

You can find more in [Panda's plotting docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) and in [plotting with error bars](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/visualization.html#visualization-errorbars).